# UIPageViewController bring subview to front after rotation

Tags: iphone, ios5, rotation, subview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController in which view I added two subviews: a transparent subview with a UITapGestureRecognizer and a toolBar with some buttons that slides up from bottom when I tap on the other subview.

EDIT.
This is the subview setup in viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated

```
CGRect frame;
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation])){
    frame = CGRectMake(50, 0, 220, 480);
}
else {
    frame = CGRectMake(50, 0, 380, 320);
}
if (!tapView) {
    tapView = [[LSTapView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    //[tapView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.4]];
    [self.view addSubview:tapView];
    [tapView release]; 
}
else {
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation])){
        [tapView setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 220, 480)];
        [fontViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 92)];
    }
    else {
        [tapView setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 380, 320)];
        [fontViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 320, 480, 92)];

    }
}

if (!fontViewController){
    fontViewController = [[LSFontViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LSFontView" bundle:nil];
}
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation])){
    [fontViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 92)];
}
else {
    [fontViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 320, 480, 92)];
}

[self.view addSubview:fontViewController.view];
```

If i change the pages without rotate the device, everything works fine in both the orientations. Nevertheless when I rotate the device, these two subviews disapper and I discover that they are not to the front. Anyway if I add this to my code:

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:tapView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:fontViewController.view];
}
```

something odd happens: I can't change the pages anymore, or better, the previous and next viewControllers are loaded correctly but they are not displayed and the pages don't change.

Someone can explain me what is happening?

Thank you. 
L.

Comment: could you show how you set up your subviews initially?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by registering the UIPageViewController to the UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didChangeOrientation) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

and by adding this simple selector:

```
-(void)didChangeOrientation{
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:tapView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:fontViewController.view];
}
```

For some reasons I don't really know and understand, the simple addition of the didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation selector messed up the data source and causes strange crashes..

Answer (score 0):

Your issue should have to do with the fact that `viewWillAppear` is not called automatically after a rotation of the device under iOS 5. Thus, when you rotate the device, you code to rearrange the subviews' frame is not executed. I don't know if this is a bug in iOS 5, or in some specific minor version of iOS 5, but I found this a few weeks ago and it also disrupted my logics in presence of autorotation.

One easy try to fix this would be:

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
   [self viewWillAppear:NO];
}
```

Let me know if this works.

In any case, I find quite puzzling that you are instantiating your views in `viewWillAppear`. IMO, the right place for that is `viewDidLoad`.

My suggestion would be for handling the logics of subview creation in `viewDidLoad` and then handling the logics of view positioning in a separate method, let's call it `layoutSubviews`, which you would call both from `viewDidLoad` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`.

Comment: could you check that viewWillAppear is executed when you rotate the device and step through it to ensure that everything happens as you expect? also check my suggestion above...

Comment: one important thing: in viewWillAppear, make sure that the device orientation is the one you are expecting...

Comment: Something very very strange is happening here.. If I only implement an empty didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation method (like this: -(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{} ) the pages are not changed anymore, even if they are correctly loaded.